# Data Augmentation with keras running out of data

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, data-augmentation

Why is this code not working, its taken directly from the book "Deep Learning with Python".. Im getting the error message:

"WARNING:tensorflow:Your input ran out of data; interrupting training. Make sure that your dataset or generator can generate at least `steps_per_epoch * epochs` batches (in this case, 50 batches). You may need to use the repeat() function when building your dataset."

Heres a snippet of the relevant code:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    rotation_range=40,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_dir,
        target_size=(150, 150),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        validation_dir,
        target_size=(150, 150),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary')

history = model.fit_generator(
      train_generator,
      steps_per_epoch=100,
      epochs=100,
      validation_data=validation_generator,
      validation_steps=50)
```

I dont understand why it want me to change the batch-size or steps_per_epoch, when it worked in the book.

Comment: Can you add code that I can reproduce with minimal amount of data? It might be that you don't have enough memory?

Comment: I am not sure that i understand what code you want me to add. 

In terms of memory, do you mean primary or secondary memory?

Comment: RAM. If you don't have enough ram. What do you call primary or secondary memory?

Comment: Remove the `steps_per_epoch` and `validation_steps`. You use those terms when using data generators that infinitely produce data. But since that is not the case for you, those terms are not required.

Comment: This worked. However, i am not sure that i understand why the other code did not work.
Doesn't the generator use data augmentation to generate different representations of my data? Based on this intuition, i cannot see how i would run out of data, since new data should be generated if needed?

Am i wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something you can try:

```
steps_per_epoch=train_generator.n//train_generator.batch_size
```

And:

```
validation_steps=validation_generator.n//validation_generator.batch_size
```

Comment: I have seen this solution in other places too. However, i do not understand why it is necessary? 

Doesn't the generator use data augmentation to generate different representations of my data? Based on this intuition, i cannot see how i would run out of data, since new data should be generated if needed? Am i wrong?

Comment: Under the hood it returns a tf.data.Dataset which does not run indefinitely. The transformations are applied randomly. It's not new images that are created indefinitely. But that's just how keras is made. In previous versions you didn't have to specify these arguments.